# Could one extend GKeyFile to hold a private ·origin· enum field via GType?

Tags: c, private, glib, user-data, gobject

I'm looking for a good solution for the following problem:

- having some keys stored in an GKeyFile structure, I've put it there from 3 distinct sources: 1) *compiled in data*, 2) *other ini file*, 3) *a plugin script*,
- I want to mark each key/value pair with the origin from which it came from.

I've stumbled upon `GType` and the examples of adding a private data member to an existing type at runtime. The examples are very straight ([link](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#g-type-class-add-private)). So I thought about adding such private field (the `origin` enum) somewhere into the GKeyFile's GType, basically to the (another GType?) type of the value in each of the key/value stored pair, but I don't know the way this should be done.

There is the [G_TYPE_KEY_FILE](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Boxed-Types.html#G-TYPE-KEY-FILE:CAPS) macro, which returns the `GType` of the `GKeyFile`. However, where to start?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a private struct to a type unless you control the implementation of the type. You don’t control the implementation of `GKeyFile` (it’s internal to GLib), so you can’t do this.

I think you would be better off writing a class which wraps the `GKeyFile` and implements your own logic on top of it. The new class would have a pointer to an internal `GKeyFile` instance, but would not be derived from `GKeyFile`, because other code doesn’t need to know that your data store is actually implemented as a key file.

Comment: Too bad… The "controlling" of the implementation is IMO too serious approach – I cannot see the somewhat clumsy (or simply slow…) GLib programming team to *change* the implementation significantly. If I could leverage GObject introspection then maybe I could discover how the type is built and extend it after all?

Comment: A member of the GLib programming team tries to help you, and you call them "clumsy", nice work... Encapsulation such as this is widely-used and generally understood to be a good idea, especially for libraries. You wouldn't be able to use GObject introspection to do this, because it won't give you any more information than you could get from the GLib header file already. Note that for GObjects, the capability that you are asking for is provided by `g_object_set_data()`, but GKeyFile isn't a GObject.